# Can't create a MySQL dump on Windows, fails before password prompt

Tags: windows, mysql, mysqldump

I'm trying to create a dump of a locally installed MySQL database on my laptop.

I am aware of the command:

```
%>mysqldump -u root -p --opt [database name]
```

but I am not able to execute it. I might be missing the obvious here.

1. I open command line manager, which prompts the root password.
2. Once I enter the password, I get straight into `mysql>`
3. I am not able to exit the `mysql>` to get back into the shell.

Above command entered:

```
mysql> mysqldump -u -root -p --opt [database]
```

gives me the following:

```
->
```

I have also tried the following:

```
C:\> cd c:\program files\mysql\...\bin 
C:\program files\mysql\...\bin> mysqldump -u root -p [database name] > dump.sql
```

Which only then reports back "Access denied".

I am not prompted the password. User is 'root'. I have full admin rights under Windows. I have tried this on two laptops with different DBs and passwords with the same result. I installed the MySQL database using the wizard.

I am lost. It seems I can only log straight into the database, but am not able to get into the shell (`shell>` ). Am I wrong just using the command line manager? Do I need workbench or something else?

Comment: Looks like the username/password is wrong. Can you double check you can connect using those details via a gui like mysql workbench?

Comment: please don't repost. Just go back and edit your old question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ths `mysqldump` executable is different from the `mysql` executable. You don't enter `mysqldump` within `mysql`, but just in a normal Windows command prompt, which you'll get by going to *Start* → *Run* → Type "cmd", Enter.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <database> > dump.sql
```

Here, `<database>` is replaced with your database name. It will prompt you for your password and dump the contents to `dump.sql`. You can specify an absolute path for the dump file as well, for example `C:\dump.sql`

See [this Howto](http://www.backuphowto.info/how-backup-mysql-mysqldump) for a few more details.

Comment: thank you, I was suspecting sth. like it. Which tool do I need, or where do I enter a 'Windows command prompt'?

Comment: Just go to Start > Run, enter `cmd`. Then you can enter the `mysqldump` line. You might want to replace `dump.sql` with `C:\Temp\dump.sql` to specify where the file really goes (see akseli's answer below).

Comment: By the way, once your DB's start growing in size, you should start looking into different compression methods to keep your dumps within reasonable sizes.

Comment: @akseli Do you know if Windows comes with an easy way to pipe through GZip?

Comment: I'll add the info to my answer. It's quite lengthy.

Comment: The C;\windows\system32\cmd.exe gives me the following error: 'mysqldump is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. The full line: C:\Users\Matthias>mysqldump -u root -p mysql > dump.sql ('the db is called mysql unfortuanetly :-)

Comment: You might need to enter the following *first*, before the `mysqldump` command: `cd C:\path\to\mysql\bin`, or wherever you installed MySQL to). @Mat

Comment: cd path seems to work, I am at the bin. sqldump command as per above triggers 'access is denied' response. I tried entering the password '-ppassword but without success. I assume I should be prompted the root password? The only user that is defined it 'root', the server is 'localhost'. Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: If your user is root, then only specify `-u root -p`. Witout a password. It will prompt for your password after that. Since you opened a new question anyway, you might want to close and accept this one, otherwise there's no point opening a new one. @Mat

Answer (score 2):

Try dumping to some directory that's not under "Program Files". Only binaries and static data as supposed to go there, not user files.

Comment: For clarification to future readers with the same problem what worked: In the windows cmd.exe C:\users\[user name]> cd c:\program files\mysql...\bin

C:\program files\mysql...\bin> mysqldump -u root -p [database name] > c:\[folder name]\dump.sql

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've had to use mysqldump, but I'm pretty sure that you have to define a destination file for the dump.

That is, try the following syntax:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases [database name] > C:\Temp\DBDump.sql
```

You don't need the --opt option, simply use either --databases [dbname] or --all-databases to dump.

Secondly, you want to make sure that you're dumping to a file, not simply on screen (unless this is what you're after).

Ok, so to compress your image you can follow the following guide posted to the MySQL 5.5 Reference Guide:

Posted by Mike Ng on May 16 2005 5:40pm [Delete] [Edit]

> Following Lon B helpful post:
>
> You can pipe it to gzip to compress in windows. I didn't think it
>   would work on windows, but apparently it does.
>
> @ECHO Beginning backup of %dbname%...
>
> %mysqldir%\bin\mysqldump -B %dbname% -u %dbuser% | gzip>
>   %bkupdir%\dbBkup_%dbname%_%yy%%mm%%dd%.sql.gz
>
> Of course,you need gng gzip in your path or directory

You can read it at the bottom of the [MySQL 5.5 Reference Guide on MYSQLDUMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

Sorry, i changed the post; I copied the wrong one ... Sorry!

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  `mysqldump` outputs to stdout. It can be (and usually is) redirected to a file, but there is no requirement to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that you are not windows command manager as an admin, and therefore, you do not have write access to program files.

Comment: I have administrator rights under Windows, and I never even get the password prompt. User is 'root'. The problem must be sth. else. I have re-installed everything on a second machine with the exact same result.

Comment: Found solution: Specify directory for dump that is not under 'program files' 

In the windows cmd.exe: 

C:\users[user name]> cd c:\program files\mysql...\bin 

C:\program files\mysql...\bin> mysqldump -u root -p [database name] > c:[folder name]\dump.sql